# How to implement a key lookup for generated keys table in pentaho Kettle

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I just started to use Pentaho Kettle for integration. Seems great so far, quite intuitive compared to Talend, which I was also investigating.

I am trying to migrate some customers without their keys. So I have their email addresses.

The customer may already exist in the database, so what I need to do is:

1. If the customer exists, add it's id to the imported field and continue.
2. But if the customer doesn't exist I need to get the next Hibernate key from the table Hibernate_Sequences and set it as the id.

But I don't want to always allocate a key, so I want to conditionally execute a step to allocate the next key.

So what I want to do, is in the flow execute the db procedure, which allocates the next key and returns it, only if there's no value in id from the "lookup id" step.

Is this possible?

[image: Existing Flow]

Just posting my updated flow - so the answer was to use a filter rows component which splits the data on true/false. I really had trouble getting the id out of the database stored proc because of a bug, so I had to use decimal and then convert back to integer (which I also couldn't figure out how to do, so used a javascript component).

[image]

Comment: great, thanks that's the one I'm looking for. Feel free to post it as an answer so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. As per official documentation (i left only valuable information) "Lookup values are added as new fields onto the stream". So u need just to put step "Filter row" in Flow section and check for "id" which suppose to be added in "Existing Id Lookup" step.